# Show that Improper integral converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

```
Show that the following integral is convergent.
```

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\sin\left(1 \over x^{2}\right)\cos\left(x^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

Not sure how I can solve this using absolute convergence

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\left\vert\,
\sin\left(1 \over x^{2}\right)\cos\left(x^{2}\right)\,\right\vert\,{\rm d}x
$$

any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, $\quad\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin\bigg(\frac1{x^2}\bigg)\cos\big(x^2\big)dx = \frac{\cos2+\sin2-e^{-2}}4\sqrt\frac\pi2$

Comment: Also, $\quad\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\cos\bigg(\frac1{x^2}\bigg)\sin\big(x^2\big)dx = \frac{\cos2+\sin2+e^{-2}}4\sqrt\frac\pi2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\left|\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\cos(x^2)\right|\le \left|\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right|\sim_\infty \frac1{x^2}$$
and the integral

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
is convergent. Conclude.

Comment: Needs an upvote to go with green!

Answer (score 1):

got it. sin(1) is a constant so you can place it as a multiple on the outside of the integral. cosx^2=1/secx^2 since cos is in the denominator when you do the trig identity 1/secx^2 you flip it to the numerator. This keeps you from having the discontinuities that cos sign has ie 1/cos(pi/2)=1/0. sec is never zero and the new integral is sin(1)*integral of secx^2/x^2 from 1 to infinity which is continuous over its range and therefore converges.

Comment: welcome to MSE.